# Django's AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE Unit Test Fails - AttributeError: 'UserSettingsHolder' object has no attribute 'AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE'

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-authentication

I am setting the AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE in my settings file like so:

```
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'api.AccountProfile'
```

And the API app is added to the installed apps like so:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    #3rd party apps
    'south',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.twitter',

    #Our apps
    'ourproject.apps.api',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    # 'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
)
```

I run `./manage.py syncdb` and `./manage.py migrate` without difficulty, and then I run the django unit tests with `./manage.py test`. The first test that fails is the AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE test, which is located at `django.contrib.auth.tests.models.ProfileTestCase`.

This particular test fails right at the beginning:

```
def test_site_profile_not_available(self):
    # calling get_profile without AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE set
    if hasattr(settings, 'AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE'):
        del settings.AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE    #<----Fails here
```

Further down the stack, I find that the error is occurring in the `__delattr__` method of `django.utils.functional.LazyObject` when `delattr` is eventually called on the wrapper:

```
def __delattr__(self, name):
    if name == "_wrapped":
        raise TypeError("can't delete _wrapped.")
    if self._wrapped is empty:
        self._setup()
    delattr(self._wrapped, name)    #<----Fails here
```

And here's the Traceback:

```
File "/path/to/python/files/django/contrib/auth/tests/models.py", line 30, in test_site_profile_not_available
    del settings.AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE
File "/path/to/python/files/django/utils/functional.py", line 211, in __delattr__
    delattr(self._wrapped, name)
AttributeError: 'UserSettingsHolder' object has no attribute 'AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE'
```

So I dug into the django source and added a few print statements to see what was going on:

django.contrib.auth.tests.models.ProfileTestCase:

```
def test_site_profile_not_available(self):
    # calling get_profile without AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE set
    if hasattr(settings, 'AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE'):
        print '*******', type(settings), '********'
        del settings.AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE

Output: ******* <class 'django.conf.LazySettings'> ********
```

django.utils.functional.LazyObject:

```
def __delattr__(self, name):
    if name == "_wrapped":
        raise TypeError("can't delete _wrapped.")
    if self._wrapped is empty:
        print 'Here I am. Rock you like a hurricane'
        self._setup()
    print '*************', hasattr(self._wrapped, name)
    print '*************', name
    print '*************', self._wrapped.AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE
    delattr(self._wrapped, name)

Output: ************* True
************* AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE
************* api.AccountProfile
```

Note that `LazySettings` inherits from `LazyObject` and has no **delattr** method of its own.

Here's the full output of `./manage.py test`: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/20560722/TestOutput.txt . Note that the test in question is only being run once, and the print statements are only showing up once.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known Django issue which has been fixed on the latest master (1.5dev) https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17966.